# Calling Transform component of an object in another class C#

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, position, transform

I am working on a tutorial and the "Side objectives" that they don't walk you through to try and get a feel for it.

So, the way things work at this time is that there is the Player object. The player object has the player script.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator anim;//reference for animator component
private Rigidbody rigidBody;//reference to component for rigidbody
private AudioSource audioSource;

[SerializeField] private float force = 100f;
[SerializeField] private AudioClip sfxJump;
[SerializeField] private AudioClip sfxDeath;


}

void Awake() {//these are assertions that will ensure when writing the cocde that you wont miss them. use for team work. 
    Assert.IsNotNull (sfxJump);
    Assert.IsNotNull (sfxDeath);

}

private bool jump = false; //check for jump 
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {//all these are getting components at the start to update them as the code goes onwards. 
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    positionStart = GetComponent<Transform> ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!GameManager.instance.GameOver && GameManager.instance.GameStarted) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {//if press mouse key
            GameManager.instance.PlayerStarted ();
            rigidBody.useGravity = true;//turn gravity on for component so it goes back down.
            audioSource.PlayOneShot (sfxJump);
            anim.Play ("jump");//play the animation jump
            jump = true;
        }
    }
}
//Fixed update for physics
void FixedUpdate() {//use this for any physics due to frame rate. time.deltatime wont cut it.
    if (jump == true) {//if we are jumping, turn the jump off.
        jump = false;
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0, 0);//turn velocity to 0 so speed doesnt increase while falling
        rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, force), ForceMode.Impulse);//give a impulse upwards.
    }

    //print (rigidBody.velocity.y);//print velocity. turn this shit off.
}
//Code to create collision with obstacles and then die and fall through the floor.
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {//call collision component
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "obstacle") {//if you slap a tagged object called obstacle
        rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector2 (-50, 20), ForceMode.Impulse);//add force to push back cause you ded
        rigidBody.detectCollisions = false;//turn off the ability to detect collisions
        audioSource.PlayOneShot (sfxDeath);//play ded noise
        GameManager.instance.PlayerCollided ();
        GameManager.instance.Restart ();

    }
    }
    }
```

---

The game manager, of course exists in the camera to control the states of the game.

```
public static GameManager instance = null;//only one in memory. only one gamemanager ever.

[SerializeField] private GameObject mainMenu;
[SerializeField] private GameObject replayBtn;
[SerializeField] private GameObject playBtn;

private bool gameEnd = false;
private bool gameStarted = false;
private bool playerActive = false;
private bool gameOver = false;

//getters setters start
public bool PlayerActive {
    get { return playerActive; }
}

public bool GameOver {
    get { return gameOver; }
}

public bool GameStarted {
    get { return gameStarted; }
}
//to create a state between gameover and main menu
public bool GameEnd {
    get {return gameEnd; }
}
//getter setters end
void Awake(){
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = this;//this means the current instance. one instance of this class.
    } else if (instance != this) {//if a seocnd one gets created destroy that bitch.
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);//allows a game object to persist between the scene. Dont need with one scene.

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    replayBtn.SetActive (false);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void PlayerCollided(){
    gameOver = true;
}

public void PlayerStarted(){
    playerActive = true;

}
public void EnterGame (){
    mainMenu.SetActive(false);
    gameStarted = true;
}
//When player dies start coroutine Hold.
public void Restart (){
    StartCoroutine (Holdexit());

}
//The hole Coroutine waits 2 seconds then turns on the menu.
IEnumerator Holdexit (){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
    playBtn.SetActive (false);
    replayBtn.SetActive (true);
    mainMenu.SetActive (true);
    //add character movement to location

}
}
```

---

So, When the player hits the object he dies, loses the ability to touch colliders and falls through the map, after 2 seconds the main menu comes back and the play button is replaced with a replay button. When I press replay, I need to reset the position, the state of the game, and the ability to collide.

I Tried all kinds of things. I did a get component for transform and tried to call it in the coroutine and then set it there, but I couldnt figure it out. I tried just changing the position after etc after the game managers state to restart gets called but the position change occurs before the main menu comes back on because its not being used in the coroutine.

Once thing I though would work, is i created a new method,

```
  public void PlayerReset (){
  if (GameManager.instance.Restart()){
  //put new changes to player here.  
   }
  }
```

The errors I came across here was I could not convert type void to bool, I assume its cause I was trying to say if the restart instance existed then function, but the way the restart function is created isn't true or false its just - is.

I really appreciate any help. I think what im going to try and do is make another script to the side and have it call the class of player to pull the components, and then manipulate them from there maybe. AUGH. So confusing. Lmao.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by only including code relevant to your specific issue. It's not currently clear what you are asking.

Comment: What happens when you simply reload the level ?

Comment: Reloading the level actually works. I didnt know it was even a function. there is some issues with it where i need to refunction the replay button to have its own settings and a few other things. Also my apologies for posting all of the script - this was the recommendation I received the last time i reached out was to post the full script to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a public `Transform` variable on your object, and then in the inspector, drag the selected transform you want to call to that variable.

When that's done, you can use that transform variable in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save the start position of the player in GameManager as it's a singleton. So, you set the position of the player to this saved position after restart.
2. You'll need to reinitialize all the variables(i.e. gameEnd,gameStarted, playerActive, gameOver etc.) on restart.
3. `if(GameManager.instance.Restart())` will not work, as **Restart()**  returns void not a boolean.

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I added, I need a little guidance if you can assist.
 [SerializeField] private Transform playerPos;

I then dragged the player into the field, and it looks like it reads the transform. This was added into the game manager. So now that its there, how do i call for it to reset the position within the restart function? new vector 3? or is there something easier I can use?

Comment: public void RestartGame (){
  transform.position = new Vector3 (-2f, 7f, 3.6f);

Was added and it did do a transform, but it was like..Only the outline of the character and not the entire thing. The object was still falling but SOMETHING did get moved. Still working on it.

Comment: You need to make rigidBody.detectCollisions=true